# T object type defined by another string in same class

Tags: c#

I'm pulling some data from an external API, and they have some objects defined by a discriminator string.

An example is an array of "Include" objects, where each one can have a different type of object as the Attributes parameter.

```
public class Include
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public T Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

How can I define what object type T is, based on the `Type` parameter's value?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json?

Comment: You want something like Type = "Foo" so you can do Attributes.Bar ? Where Bar is a property of a class called Baz?

Comment: @Eonasdan Yep, exactly...

Comment: @aepot Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define Attributes as a JObject, then do .ToObject based on what the Type value is.

```
public class Include
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public JObject Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Then do an if (or switch) statement to handle each Type:

```
if (include.Type == "TypeOne")
  ProcessTypeOne(include.Attributes.ToObject<TypeOne>());
else
  ...
```

That's assuming you have a class defined for each possible "Type".  Or you can process them however you need to, just convert the Attributes to the necessary Type via the .ToObject<>() method.

Comment: Hmm okay, but that would then have to be done everywhere this object is being parsed, right?

Comment: It would, but I really can't see how you're going to be able to avoid that, even if you could use a generic to define it.  Every time you use it, won't you have to know the type and use that particular type accordingly?

Comment: Somewhat.. except there's a lot of these in their APIs, and they are often being used pretty deep in the model, so it would require quite a lot of custom code for each API request.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUnifB):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //setup
        var a = new Include{Type = "Baz", Attributes = new Baz{Prop1 = "hello"}};
        //convert
        var b = Convert.ChangeType(a.Attributes, Type.GetType(a.Type));
        //use
        Console.WriteLine(b.Prop1);
    }
}

public class Include
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public dynamic Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Baz
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

`Convert.ChangeType` would allow you to convert the dynamic object to whatever type it needed to be. However you may still find that you are in same place as [@BraianM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922176/237917) and will have to type check so you know that a property or method is there.

You could also look at [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm). Perhaps there is something there that would help.